# Trouble with Bootstraps typeahead in angular 5

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angular, typescript

I am having a difficult time getting Bootstraps typeahead in angular 5 working would appreciate some advice. The problem I have is that I don't know how to set the input field to equal the city + state for exaple "New york, NY" in bootstraps search method example. I am new to Typescript and the new fat arrow feature in JavaScript any help would be greatly appreciated.

**model array of objects**

```
public model: any;
```

**example of data that I am getting**

```
  {
    "city":"New York",
    "latitude":40.7127837,
    "longitude":-74.0059413,
    "state":"New York",
    "stateCode":"NY"
   }
```

**Search method here I am trying to set the location items to filter 'city,'+'state'**

```
  search = (text$: Observable<string>) => text$
  .debounceTime(200)
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .map(term => term.length < 2 ? [] : this.locationItems.filter(item => item.city.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1).slice(0, 10));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arrow function inside the last `map` in your chain needs to *map* (transform) the value of the string the user has typed into the search box to an array of items that will be presente to the user as suggestions.

You start nice, by askin if term is only one character long (or an empty string) and do nt even run the search, imediatelly returning empty array. For the other part, you need to find which items you want to present to the user.

This part depends on your business logic, but I assume that you want user to be searching by either `state` or `stateCode`? Anyway, this part is your business logic and you can change and improve it according to your busniess model. I'm giving a very simply function in the code below.

```
// util function
// returns true if the "term" can be used to match the "item" from your data
// change this according to your business logic
function matches(term: string, item: Item): boolean {
  return item.state.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase())
    || item.stateCode.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase())
}
```

The lambda in the last `map` can be like this.

```
term => {
  if (term.length < 2) {
    return []
  }

  // arary of matching results
  const matching = this.filter(item => matches(term, item))

  // now we transform this to the format you specified
  const formatted = matching.map(item => `${item.state}, ${item.stateCode}`)

  return formatted
  // you can also .slice(0, 10) here like you did in your example to keep the number of suggestions no more than 10
}
```